# MVC3 - Error rendering partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

why does this error occur.. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments...when I am trying to put a partial view in a div like

```
  <div>@Html.RenderPartial("_pagePartial");</div>
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the correct syntax is this (notice the `{ }`s):

```
<div>@{Html.RenderPartial("_pagePartial");}</div>
```

or if you prefer:

```
<div>@Html.Partial("_pagePartial")</div>
```

The reason for this is that contrary to the `Partial` extension method `RenderPartial` doesn't return anything. It directly writes to the output stream. Contrast this with the WebForm equivalents:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("_pagePartial"); %>
<%= Html.Partial("_pagePartial") %>
```